# How to convert Date to timestamp using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I used MomentJS to convert local date to UTC date using the following way:

```js
$("#div1").text(moment("2016-10-11 18:06:03").tz("Europe/Paris").format());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.6/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Now I need timestamp from the output value using MomentJS.

Comment: Do you want value in Unix time-stamp ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You said:

> I used MomentJS to convert local date to UTC date using the following way:
>   `moment("2016-10-11 18:06:03").tz("Europe/Paris").format()`

That doesn't do that.  That converts a local value to Paris time, and emits it as a string in ISO8601 format.

> Now I need timestamp from the output value using MomentJS.

That's a different question, and wouldn't involve the output of the above because:

1. You can't get a timestamp from the output string, you'd get it from a `moment` object.  You could *parse* that string, but that would be silly since you already had a `moment` object earlier.
2. Timestamps are UTC based, so time zone conversion is irrelevant.  You'd get the same timestamp if you didn't convert at all.

You can get a string with a timestamp using `.format('X')` or `.format('x')` depending on which precision you want.  But it's much cleaner to just get the numerical timestamp using `.valueOf()` or `.unix()`, again depending on precision.

Comment: This worked for me  :   var dt= moment(timestamp).tz('Europe/Paris').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

Answer (score 46):

```
moment().format("X"); // lowercase 'x' for milliseconds
```

```js
var date = moment('2016-10-11 18:06:03').tz('Europe/Paris').format(),
    timestamp = moment(date).format("X");

$('#div1').text(date);
$('#timestamp').text(timestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="timestamp"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the time from the date use the format method of momentjs

```js
var date = moment('2016-10-11 18:06:03').tz('Europe/Paris').format();
 

console.log(date);
console.log(moment(date).format("X"));
console.log(moment(date).format("x")); // for milliseconds
console.log(moment(date).format("HH:mm"));
console.log(moment(date).format("hh:mm A"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to expand on something mentioned earlier. These generate the results.

```
// less precision
moment().unix() === moment().format('X')  // uppercase X

// more precision
moment().valueOf() === moment().format('x')  // lowercase x
```

Hope that sheds some light

Answer (score 5):

I think `moment().unix()` do the trick !
See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/