# How to convert a date string into date with timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an input `'Fri Aug 16 16:06:38 CDT 2019'` expected output is `4:06 PM Friday` assuming I am in **Central Time Zone**

expected output for Some one in Eastern Timezone is  `5:06 PM Friday`

I just get an error in the below snippet

```js
const input = 'Fri Aug 16 16:06:38 CDT 2019';
const date = moment(input).format('dddd MMM DD HH:MM:SS ZZZ YYYY');

console.log('date', date);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146839/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-using-momentjs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Date to timestamp using MomentJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146839/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-using-momentjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need a format to tell `moment` how to *parse* the datestring provided, not how to display it. For that purpose, you should use `moment` constructor with two parameters - [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

And don't forget that format is case-sensitive. `MM` is a code for month, so you should use `mm` instead to parse minutes (and `ss` for seconds). As for output, you need to call `local()` on the given date object to use local time to display a moment instead of the original moment's time.

However, there's another caveat here: `momentjs` doesn't know how to process abbreviated offsets (like CDT, PST and so on) in this type of workflow; it only supports their subset in RFC2822 parsing workflow since [this PR](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/3708).

You can implement it on your own, of course, using the table in that request to replace the abbreviations with timezone offsets, then proceed with `ZZ` flag. Like this:

```js
const replaceAbbr = (() => dtstr => {
  const rfc2822Timezones = {
    ' GMT': ' +0000',
    ' EDT': ' -0400',
    ' EST': ' -0500',
    ' CDT': ' -0500',
    ' CST': ' -0600',
    ' MDT': ' -0600',
    ' MST': ' -0700',
    ' PDT': ' -0700',
    ' PST': ' -0800'
  };
  return dtstr.replace(/ [A-Z]{2}T/, abbr => rfc2822Timezones[abbr] || abbr);
})();

const input = 'Fri Aug 16 16:06:38 CDT 2019';
const inputWithTz = replaceAbbr(input);
const date = moment(inputWithTz, 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY', 'en');

console.log('output in UTC: ', date.utc().format('h:mm A dddd'));
// output in UTC:  9:06 PM Friday

console.log('output in local: ', date.local().format('h:mm A dddd'));
// depends
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I actually have used a third parameter here to specify the locale, just in case it's not 'en'. Locale is used to parse both day-of-week and month value here.

Comment: So i see `000Z` how can I attach CDT timezone to this date ?  basically input is a server timestamp and I want to convert it into the date according to the timezone the browser is in e..g actual date is in CDT Chicago guy sees `4:06` New York guy sees `3:06` in this format `4:06 PM Friday`

Comment: Updated the answer (didn't pay attention to the expected output, sorry; was thinking the only problem is how to handle the input).

Comment: Thanks, this is `16:06:38 CDT` I am in EST so I should see output as `5:06 PM` that was the major issue for me, how can i see time adjusted based upon the browser's timezone

Comment: Doesn't show any difference to me  this is what i see
`output in UTC:  8:06 PM Friday
output in local:  4:06 PM Friday` should be `output in local:  5:06 PM Friday`

Comment: Argh, I see. It's CDT without any info on actual shift, and that's not parsed by momentjs currently. :( Sadly, moment.tz() doesn't seem to be helpful here either, as it processes timezone by its fullname, not by an abbreviation.

Comment: @dota2pro Updated my answer once again, with short implementation of that `CDT` parsing, based on commit pulled into momentjs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format :

```js
const input = 'Fri Aug 16 16:06:38 CDT 2019';
const date = moment(input).format('hh:mm A dddd');

console.log('date', date);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see `Warning: Deprecation warning: value provided is not .... ` and how are you checking what time zone is the user currently in ?

Comment: @dota2pro it is under that warning

Comment: will this adjust  automatically if a user from Eastern timezone views this ? he should see `3:06`

Comment: Whoever wrote this (and upvoted) clearly doesn't use Chrome. In my case, it's deprecation warning plus error shown as an output. The problem in the OP's post is still there; it's about how to tell momentjs how to parse that format, not about how to display it.

Comment: @dota2pro you can try to change `CDN` on your input to something like `GMT-4` which represents EST

Comment: How can i do that using moment ? this is `16:06:38 CDT` I am in EST so I should see output as `5:06 PM` that was the major issue for me